# Is it possible to create a dynamic Wikipedia portal subpage using URL parsed arguments?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata, wikimedia

I manage the Chronic Pain project on Wikidata and I have in the idea to build a portal in Wikidata.

I would like to create for each concept related to chronic pain a webpage that gather all links to associated concepts from wikidata, as well as scientific articles that are both linked to that concept and to chronic pain.

Creating such "link page" for each associated medical concept would lead to a hudge portal architecture and take a lot of time.

Instead I had in the idea that the link page should be a dynamic webpage that is built on the go, using a parameter taken from the URL. Let's say a Wikipedia page name.

My first idea was to create a separated app on Wikimedia servers that delivers the content.

Another approach could be a Wikipedia portal page that print a dynamically generated content using a Lua script. However I don't know if this is even possible to create dynamic Wikipedia pages that accept URL parsed arguments?

Comment: easy to do. populate your portal with SPARQL queries.

Comment: Yes of course. But there is many data that I would like to provide on each item. So that there shall be a subpage for each major concept related to chronic pain. I had in the idea to avoid this and to make a single dynamic page where i pass the concept's wikipedia page in the URL.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Scholia](https://tools.wmflabs.org/scholia/topic/Q1088113)?

Comment: Sort of. Do you have a sugestion ? I plan to add a link to scholia for every concept on the portal. The main limitation is that I cannot pass parameters in the URL to generate the list of scholarly articles linked to chronic pain + the concept. (ie, if the concept is Behcet disease, I need to generate a list of articles pointing to Behcet Disease AND (Chronic pain OR Neuropatic pain OR Fibromyalgia).

Comment: i'm interested: which values in Wikidata are you unable to access via SPARQL? Or perhaps you are saying that there are Wikidata values that cannot be aggregated using logical AND/OR operations. Would be interested to know of such examples.

Comment: It will work with SPARQL. It is just a question of presenting it in an user friendly interface.

Comment: If I use Wikipedia's pages for presenting the data I will end up with one page per concept. So maybe 100 pages to create. Using a single dynamic page is simpler.